# jQuery supersized doesn't show a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

I'm trying to make a simple slideshow on the background with Supersized, however for some reason it seems to only show one slide.

```
$.supersized({
        slideshow           :   1,
        autoplay            :   1,
        slide_interval      :   1000,
        transition          :   1,  // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed    :   1000,
        min_height          :   0,
        min_width           :   0,
        horizontal_center   :   1,
        fit_portrait        :   1,
        slides              :   images
    })
```

When I check what's inside 'images', it returns me an array with 2 objects, but when I check the source code, I can see it's only showing one images, while it should normally show an 'ul' with all images.

[image]

Comment: Is your jQuery inside a document ready call?

Comment: Can you dump the contents of the images variable to console (e.g. the output of `console.log(images)`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you're loading the appropriate 'supersized' js file. I believe there is a difference between the `supersized.3.2.7.js` found in the 'slideshow' folder, and the `supersized.core.3.2.1.js` located in the 'Core' folder. I think 'core' doesn't include the slideshow feature.

Comment: Aha, that does indeed fix it, I wasn't aware that the core is different from the one int he demo. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help, I just had the same problem.

Comment: I have same problem as this question so I dont add new question, just the difference is that I am adding right files...slider works(option:6) but fade (option:1) doesn't work. Any ideas?